# Dual of Riesz basis with opt. stab. const. $\lambda_\min$, $\lambda_\max$ has opt. stab. const. $\frac1{\lambda_\max}$ and $\frac1{\lambda_\min}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Consider a Hilbert space. Consider a Riesz basis $\phi_k$, $k \in \mathcal{K}$ of this space, where $\mathcal{K}$ is an appropriate set of indices.

By definition, the Riesz basis fulfils the following condition.

$\lambda_{\min} \| x \|^2  \leq \sum_{k \in \mathcal{K} } | \alpha_k | ^ 2\leq \lambda_{\max} \| x \|^2$

Assume that $\lambda_{\min}$ is chosen to be maximal and $\lambda_{\max}$ minimal such that the above condition is met. Call this choice of $\lambda_{\min}$, $\lambda_{\max}$  the optimal stability constants.

Consider the basis dual to $\phi_k$, call it $\tilde{\phi}_k$. By definition, the dual basis meets the condition.

$\langle \phi_i, \tilde{\phi}_k \rangle = \delta_{i-k}$

Here $\delta_0 = 1$ and $\delta_l = 0$ for $l \neq 0$.

Prove that the dual of Riesz basis with optimal stability constants $\lambda_\min$, $\lambda_\max$ is a Riesz basis with optimal stability constants $\frac1{\lambda_\max}$ and  $\frac1{\lambda_\min}$.

I would also appreciate incomplete hints at the solution.